# Javascript Regex Custom Replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How do I get the following conversion using Regex?

Content(input data structure):

```
a-test
b-123
c-qweq
d-gdfgd
e-312
```

Conversion:

```
1-test
2-123
3-qweq
4-gdfgd
Final-312
```

---

```
var index = 1;
function c_replace() {
  if(index == 5) { return "Final"; } 
  return index++;
}
```

Comment: What is the input data structure?

Comment: what is the rule according to which you change the 1st character? a=1, b=2 etc.?

Comment: @AlonYampolski it seems to just be sequential according to the code posted.

Comment: @vlaz except it's `Final` at the end

Comment: I want to call the function at each match.but i don't know how to do

Comment: @a.gulcan you say the input listed is the input data structure but that doesn't give us the information needed. *What* holds that information? Is it an array, or a single string with multiple lines? Maybe an array with multiline strings? Something else?

Comment: @vlaz my problem is invoke the function in every match. The input and  output is not important. The important thing is how I can call the function and change the data in every match.It's String not array

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: @a.gulcan but you'll do that differently based on *how* you do the matches. If you have a string you'd do the regex matching in one way, if you have an array, it'd be differently. For example, a stateful regex won't work with an array, you'd have to inverse the match to do a string against regex, as opposed to regex and feed it a string.

Comment: @vlaz the function was not called every time it was used with parentheses at first.I solved problem input.replace(/.-/g,c_replace)

Comment: @a.gulcan your question was quite misleading. You said a *custom* replace, and you were using the `String#replace` method. You further talked about calling a function *on each match* which is a different thing altogether - a match would be if you do `regex.exec(string)` or `string.match(regex)` or maybe even `string.test(string)`. This is why it's important to supply people with the information needed. If you had given the code, we would have been able to point out where the error was, instead of trying to figure out what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go :D

```js
// i assume you have a string input that contains linebreaks due to your question format
const input = `a-test
b-123
c-qweq
d-gdfgd
e-312`.trim(); // removing whitespace in front or behind the input data.

//splitting the lines on whitespace using \s+
const output = input.split(/\s+/).map((s, i, a) => {
  // this will map your pattern asd-foooasdasd
  const data = s.match(/^[a-z]+-(.+)$/);
  // you may want to tweak this. right now it will simply throw an error.
  if (!data) throw new Error(`${s} at position ${i} is a malformed input`);
  // figure out if we are in the final iteration
  const final = i == a.length -1;
  // the actual output data
  return `${final ? "Final" : (i + 1)}-${data[1]}`;
  // and of course join the array into a linebreak separated list similar to your input.
}).join("\n");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks answer I found the cause of the error, but this answer also works.

Answer (score 1):

Test

```js
var index=1;
var text=`a-test
b-123
c-qweq
d-gdfgd
e-312`;
function c_replace() {
  if(index == 5) { return "Final-"; } 
  return index++ +'-';
}
console.log(text.replace(/.-/g,c_replace));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = [
  'a-test',
  'b-123',
  'c-qweq',
  'd-gdfgd',
  'e-312'
];

var output = input.map((e, i) => ++i + e.slice(1));
output[output.length - 1] = 'Final' + output[output.length - 1].slice(1);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: If there can me more than 1 char before `-`, use `split('-')`

Comment: I solved. input.replace(/.-/g,c_replace) my fault was due to using brackets (input.replace(/.-/g,c_replace()) )